# facebook share link wont show image from my server

Tags: facebook, image, share

I am trying to share a from my site on facebook
and it just wont display the image.
I tried the debug tool 
and it says that every thing is ok...

the most wired thing is that when I put the same page on a different server it works fine!!!

and how can I clear the facebook cache ?

thanks alot

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.playnet.co.il%2Flogo1.jpg – _“Could not retrieve data from URL.”_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that there is not a setting on your server preventing Facebook from programmatically scraping the image data.  I have recently run across this issue where the settings on a server were restrictively secure to the extent where Facebook was not able to grab the image data for sharing purposes and make a copy of the image into its CDN.

Comment: What do you call this setting?
How can I to identify it?